# Digital Piano Midi Latency Problem

Tags: midi, digital-piano, latency

I'm connecting Casio cdp-230r to PC(windows 7) using Ableton 10 and I'm experiencing massive Latency.

Sound driver: ASIO4ALL(I've also tried with audio interface+ASIO).

I know about reducing buffer size. Also, I know midi latency couldn't be 0 seconds. When I choose minimum buffer size, latency is still huge. I've also tried using the digital piano as only midi controller(so that piano doesn't have sound, even when its volume is up). Unfortunately I couldn't find anything on that matter on the internet. Everyone is talking about reducing buffer size. I've also tried changing Midi Clock Sync Delay, Sync Type etc in Ableton in Midi Ports(Link MIDI), still nothing.

So, does anyone have the same problem with Casio cdp series or any digital piano? And can this problem be solved or the specific digital pianos just can't work as midi without annoying latency? P.S. I haven't checked using another DAW, I've only tried using Ableton.

Comment: How are you connecting the keyboard? Are you plugging a USB cable directly from the keyboard to the computer, or are you using MIDI cables to connect the keyboard to a MIDI adapter or interface? What virtual instrument are you using in Live? Do you have any audio effects or MIDI effects loaded in Live?

Comment: A MIDI interface's latency is so small that it should not be noticeable; try checking if you get the same latency with something like [VMPK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vmpk/). I suspect that your problem is with the sound output, i.e., the MIDI synthesizer, or with the audio hardware.

Comment: Try the keyboard in a friend's computer to confirm there isn't a problem with the keyboard or the connecting cable. Next step is to stop programs on your PC that are not involved in making sounds. Stop your mail client, web browser, and reduce the number of programs that show up as little icons in the task bar. Switch off WiFi. Check to see if your virus checker is scanning your computer. If so, pause it while you run the tests. Then see if latency reduces.

Comment: ASIO4All is not the most efficient ASIO driver.  What soundcard do you have?  It may have its own ASIO driver available.  For example, Realtek has their own ASIO driver, which is better than ASIO4All, but still behind dedicated low-latency interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

It will be the digital piano. Casio's lower range keyboards are known for it. Even when you buy the best cable there is and connect it to something like an iPad Pro, it still has about an eighth of a second delay.

Comment: Yes, that's my experience too. I have this cheapo 25 keyboard, which has a lot of latency, and in exactly the same setup (same DAW, drivers, vst's etc.) I experience a lot less latency with my more expensive 61 keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

ASIO4ALL is just a CPU emulation of real ASIO and it's always slower than hardware supported ASIO. So check if your audiocard supports hardware ASIO. If it doesn't - you can either buy a new one or just accept that it can't do it with appropriate latency.

Comment: "CPU emulation" doesn't really describe what ASIO4All does. It implements the ASIO programming interface on top of WASAPI, which itself may be fast or slow depending on the hardware and possible driver. Windows 10 has many improvements to WASAPI over Windows 7, so it's worth it to upgrade.

Comment: @ojs hmm.. didn't know about WASAPI, thanx for hint, it's valueble info for better understanding. But anyway, topicstarter has to get an a/c with h/w ASIO support for lower latency :)